# Django python script with command line arguments

Tags: python, django, shell, arguments

I am attempting to run a script through the django shell that uses command line arguments. My script looks like the following:

```
#...
import sys
arguments = sys.argv
# do stuff based on the arguments
```

so I tried to run the following in the command line:

```
python manage.py shell >> my_script.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

which gave me `CommandError: Command doesn't accept any arguments`

I would like to avoid using standard input, although I understand that it is a fall back plan. So **is there a way to have a python script that requires command line arguments to run through the django shell?**

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Have you looked into django management commands? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: So I have a script that, if it didn't require Django, could be executed in the command line as python myscript.py arg1 arg2. But when I try and run it through the Django shell, it fails

Comment: Ok but what are you aming for? Could you run it via a view? Why do you want to use the django-shell

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer because the script takes a couple days to run. So a view is not the purpose of it. I was using a view with celery, but there is a problem with celery right now, so I wrote a quick script that would do the same thing that can be manually run until we figure out the issue with celery for this.

Comment: Tough one... Did you look into the subprocess module? You could start this via a view. E.g. Button on a webpage. Than it spawns the process and runs it in the background.

Comment: But why do you need to run it through the django shell? Seems strange. Can't you just import what you need in your script?

Comment: @jproffitt I believe I cannot get passed certain db and server permissions without running it through the django shell.